# Keep a floated element on the same line in a WPF FlowDocument

Tags: wpf, xaml, flowdocument

I have googled for hours and while there are plenty of examples on how to float WPF elements, I am having difficulty getting two simple elements that are floated on the same line. Here is my code

```
<FlowDocument ColumnWidth="999999">
        <Section>
            <Paragraph>
                <Floater HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200">
                    <Paragraph>
                            <Run Text="Hello World Left"/>
                    </Paragraph>
                </Floater>
                <Floater HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="200">
                    <Paragraph>
                            <Run Text="Hello World Right"/>
                    </Paragraph>
                </Floater>
            </Paragraph>
        </Section>
</FlowDocument>
```

I would expect these to appear on the same line on the left and right hand side of the page. However the right hand side one gets shifted down by a line:

[image]

How can I keep the right hand side floated element at the same height as the left?

Comment: I *think* width is ignored with `Floater` and they take the width of their column. Check the [Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.floater%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Remarks) section for `Floater` on MSDN.

Comment: On closer reading of the examples, it looks like width is specified as a double representing the ratio of its width to the width of its parent. So `0.5` would be half the column width.

Comment: The comments on the example on MSDN seems to disagree with what the documentation says, so I'm not sure how it actually works.  I would recommend testing a value of something like `0.33` to see it it has any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know why it works (might do with the hanging or indent), set an empty run as the first Inline of the Paragraph:

```
               <Paragraph >
                    <Run /> 
                    <Floater HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="AliceBlue" 
                             BaselineAlignment="TextBottom" Width="200">
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Run Text="Hello World Left"/>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </Floater>
                    <Floater HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="AntiqueWhite" 
                             BaselineAlignment="TextBottom" Width="200">
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Run Text="Hello World Right"/>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </Floater>
                </Paragraph>
```